# MacBook Pro CPU temperature too high?

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu-temperature

I have a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019, Intel), and the CPU temperature when the computer is idle, is around 70° Celsius:

[image]

Is this a normal temperature for the idle status, or is this temperature too high?

Comment: Looks high for idle and fans are running fast. Did you check if they are clogged up with dust?

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Defining what I mean by "idle": The Mac is running a Parallels VM (Windows 10) which at the moment of measurement is idle.

Comment: You could take the lower case off and have a look. See https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+16-Inch+2019+Battery+Replacement/135185  for instructions.

Comment: I am afraid of taking such a high risk.